# Pod in pending state getting error : invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.PersistentVolumeSpec.accessModes: got "string", expected "array",

Tags: kubernetes

My pod is in pending state. i am deploying jenkins pod in kubernetes i am getting the following error when i describe the pod

**error: error validating "pv.yml": error validating data: [ValidationError(PersistentVolume.spec.accessModes): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.PersistentVolumeSpec.accessModes: got "string", expected "array", ValidationError(PersistentVolume.spec.nodeAffinity.required.nodeSelectorTerms): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.NodeSelector.nodeSelectorTerms: got "map", expected "array"]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false**

My vc.Yml file

```
      apiVersion: v1
         kind: PersistentVolume
         metadata:
           name: jenkins-pv-volume
           labels:
             type: local
         spec:
           storageClassName: jenkins-storage
           claimRef:
              name: jenkins-pv-claim
              namespace: jenkins
           capacity:
            storage: 10Gi
          accessModes:
            ReadWriteOnce
         hostPath:
           path: /mnt/jenkins-vol
         nodeAffinity:
           required:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
             matchExpressions:
                 key: kubernetes.io/hostname
                 operator: In
                 values: central-harbor
```

please advice

Comment: You should almost never manually create PersistentVolume objects.  The cluster will usually have a _storage provisioner_ that can create its own PersistentVolume given a PersistentVolumeClaim.  Can you just delete this object entirely?

Comment: delete ? have to remove this part                                                                                
  kind: PersistentVolume
         metadata:
           name: jenkins-pv-volume
           labels:
             type: local

Comment: I'd expect you to be able to delete the entire `pv.yaml` file you quote in the question.

Comment: if i delete the complete file pv.yaml then where i have to mention the node where the pod to be created.  is this can be mentioned in the deployment.yaml

Comment: Assuming the cluster storage provisioner creates the PersistentVolume, the cluster will also have the ability to either move the volume to where the Pod is scheduled or limit the Pod to Nodes where the storage is available.  You should not have to do anything manually for this case.

Comment: In such case i cant define that my pod need to be created in particular node ? or it will do the node selection and create the pod based on the availability no need to mention node affinity separately .   I referred this URL to create yaml files  https://devopscube.com/setup-jenkins-on-kubernetes-cluster/

Comment: I have delete  pv.yml file do i have to do anything in the deployment.yaml  after deleting the pv.yml file still i am getting the node affinity conflict error Warning  FailedScheduling  22m (x3057 over 2d3h)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }, that the pod didn't tolerate, 2 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the definition of `accessModes` as follows:

```
          accessModes:
            - ReadWriteOnce
```

The setting `accessModes` expects and `array`, not a `string`.
See the [example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistent-volumes) in the kubernetes documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your response i have modified the file as mentioned still i am getting the error            error validating data: ValidationError(PersistentVolume.spec.nodeAffinity.required.nodeSelectorTerms): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.NodeSelector.nodeSelectorTerms: got "map", expected "array"; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Comment: Now the error is in the `nodeAffinity` declaration. You declared `nodeSelectorTerms` as a map but the specification requires here an array. If you check at the documentation you'll see that `- matchExpressions:` is the right syntax (the dash before `matchExpressions` means: the following line is an array).

Comment: See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-pods-nodes-using-node-affinity/#schedule-a-pod-using-required-node-affinity

Comment: I  modified as mentioned now I am getting this ---> error parsing pv.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 23: did not find expected '-' indicator

Comment: Thats indentation error got it corrected but now as you mentioned i removed the Persisitentvolume block its says error validating data: kind not set;

Comment: Kubernetes cannot guess the `type` of the configuration file if you remove it.

Comment: I am now getting the following error                                                                             
    The PersistentVolume "jenkins-pv-volume" is invalid:
* spec.persistentvolumesource: Forbidden: spec.persistentvolumesource is immutable after creation


* nodeAffinity: Invalid value: core.VolumeNodeAffinity{Required:(*core.NodeSelector)(0xc009f083a8)}: field is immutable

Comment: Should be another question. "is immutable after creation": looks like you are trying to create a volume that already exists.